# How to design a table for postgres sql which has picture and many other text field by spring boot

Tags: postgresql, image, spring-boot

Storing photo or a large binary file in RDMS is not recommended. So I would like to store the photo in the server filesystem and only save the photo location in the Postgres SQL. Now my entity looks like this:-

```
@Entity
public class Profile {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull
String displayName;

String picturePath;

@NotNull
Date birthDate;

@NotNull
String gender;
}
```

Controller class as:-

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/profile")
public ResponseEntity<?> addorUpdateProfile(@RequestBody Profile profile) {
    profileService.saveOrUpdateExpense(profile);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Expense added succcessfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I have to store the actual photo from the user. So I have should have MultipartFile file in my post request. So later I tried to update my controller as:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/profile")
public ResponseEntity<?> addorUpdateExpense(@RequestBody Profile profile, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // I will save the file here. 
    profileService.saveOrUpdateExpense(profile);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Expense added succcessfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But I try by postman I get an error:-

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-02-24T16:48:24.117+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------427089632904546982882381;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/profile"
}
```

Postman request:-

[image]

How do I design my table or controller? To meet these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it as follows:-

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/profile" , consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public ResponseEntity<?> addOrUpdateProfile(@RequestPart("profile") Profile profile,  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("file name:"+file.getOriginalFilename()+" file is here. Save it");
    profileService.saveOrUpdateExpense(profile);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Profile added succcessfully", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

For testing by curl try this post request:-

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'  -F profile='{ "displayName": "ma ma",  "birthDate": "1999-01-01", "gender": "male"};type=application/json' -F file=@'/home/dev/Downloads/file.pdf;type=application/octet-stream'   http://localhost:8080/profile
```